# The use of collaboration frameworks(collaborative software or groupware) for rss feeds

Tags: rss, collaboration, collaborative

I have to survey this topic but I can't find useful articles which are academic. Also, I have to answer this question - what are the standards and format of rss feeds?
                                       thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the relationship between collaboration frameworks and [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feeds as follow: collaboration frameworks provide support to rss feeds as a way to communicate (export) updates of something or to import communication from other systems. Here is a list of three academic papers somehow related to collaboration frameworks or the use of rss feeds to create systems.

[Florian Rosenberg, Francisco Curbera, Matthew J. Duftler, Rania Khalaf, "Composing RESTful Services and Collaborative Workflows: A Lightweight Approach," IEEE Internet Computing, pp. 24-31, September/October, 2008](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/MIC.2008.98)

[Evaluating Web 2.0 Services Based on 7C Framework](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5070905)

[A Framework for Flexible User Profile Mashups](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.9648)

The answer for you last question you can find in this link: [RSS specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#External_links).